# Define array of <String, String[]> in JAVA and initialize

Tags: java

In JAVA how do I define and initialiaze the following data successfully ?

```
Array<String, String[]> BB = 
 {"name1", {"a", "b", "c"}, 
  "name2", {"d", "e"}}
```

Above statements give syntax error . Thanks for advise!

Comment: There are no tuples in Java. Explain what `<String, String[]>` is.

Comment: In Java, the closes thing to that will be a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Comment: It looks as though you are trying to write some other language in Java. Generally, writing in language X using the idioms from language Y results, at the very best, in stilted, unidiomatic code. Much better back off to the problem you are trying to solve, and ask how best to solve that in Java.

Comment: Correct, Patricia. I have an app written in PHP and want to rewrite it in Java for Android. In  PHP, this structure can be done very easy. Thanks. Will try find the best (and easiest) way for Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to define a class that has a `String` and a `String[]` fields inside it, like this:

```
class MyClass {
    String field1;
    String[] field2;
    public MyClass(String field1,String[] field2) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
    }
}
```

And then declare the list:

```
List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
    new MyClass("name1", new String[] { "a", "b", "c" }),
    new MyClass("name2", new String[] { "d", "e" })
    ));
```

Another option may be to have a `Map<String, List<String>>`, in case your first `String` is used as an index:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("name1", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
map.put("name2", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("d", "e"));
```

A third option may be using a multimap that basically is a `Map<K, Collection<V>>`. Guava offers a [`MultiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) interface to work with, and several ways to initialize it.

Comment: Thanks Luiggi et al/ I will use List and MyClass style for this case.